# Do I still need to specify all three `border-radius`, `-moz-border-radius` and `-webkit-border-radius` when creating border radius in modern browsers?

Tags: css, border

I'm creating a website that uses border radius. I found many tutorials that show this example:

```
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
```

This example shows that I've to specify border radius for all three browser engines.

It appears this info just gets copied around. Is this still true today in August 2015? Do I've to do it or is this just outdated info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to use `border-radius` for all modern browsers.

According to

http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius

https://css-tricks.com/do-we-need-box-shadow-prefixes/

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **No**

Modern browsers supports these attributes !

Just use : `border-radius: 10px`

[Compatibility Table](http://caniuse.com/#search=border%20radius)

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to. Check out the w3scools reference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp